# First record date in one table id in another PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have two tables seed and relation:

- seed: `created_at`, `relation_id`
- relation: `user_id`, `relation_id`

Each user can have multiple relations.

For each user I want its first relation so the min(created_at) but I can't figure out how to do this because user_id is in one table and created_at in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the two table, then use group by:

```
select r.user_id, min(s.created_at)
from seed s 
  join relation r on r.relation_id = s.relation_id
group by r.user_id;
```